# Corebluetooth unable to reconnect to BLE device while in the background

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to use corebluetooth to connect to a BLE device while in background mode. I already have have background mode working and currently receives disconnection callbacks while backgrounded.

I create the manager like this

```
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil,
                                              options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: "myCentralManagerIdentifier"])
```

I then implement the scan with

```
centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil,
                                                  options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
```

then I connect to the device after the scan with

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        if peripheral.name == "My BLE" {
            self.peripheral = peripheral
            self.peripheral.delegate = self
            centralManager.stopScan()
            // Connect!
            centralManager.connect(self.peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }
```

Now when the app is backgrounded, and the BLE disconnect, I get this call back (which is good, it shows that background mode and state restoration is working)

```
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                            didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                            error: Error?)
        {
            print("Disconnected")
            peripheral.delegate = self
            centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
```

I immediately try to reconnect. But even when the device comes back online, I never receive any call back. **I was under the impression that the way this API work is that the OS will attempt the connection for me while my app is in background and when the BLE is back online I will get notified?**

I have the following delegate method to let me know when it is connected

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        //send some user notifications and logs
        alert()
    }
```

didConnect is called when the first connection is made but is not called the second time when the BLE device comes backonline while in background

According to apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1)

> When the user leaves home, the iOS device may eventually become out of
> range of the lock, causing the connection to the lock to be lost. At
> this point, the app can simply call the connectPeripheral:options:
> method of the CBCentralManager class, and because connection requests
> do not time out, the iOS device will reconnect when the user returns
> home.

Comment: What do you mean "when the app is killed?" If the app if force-quit by the user, you will not run `didDisconnectPeripheral`. Force-quit is immediate. No code will run. Do you mean something else by "the app is killed" (such as being being put into the background, or terminated due to memory pressure)? You definitely should not expect anything when BLE is turned on. You wouldn't expect anything at all until the connection is completed. To get that requires setting background modes that you haven't discussed. Your descriptions in the first paragraph don't match later descriptions.

Comment: Question updated with the right terms

Comment: How do you expect to be notified? Do you have a `centralManager(_:didConnect:)` method? The docs are correct. If you call `connect` and a connection happens, you will be notified if you have the rest of the system configured correctly. If your application is actually terminated, then you need to explore BLE State Restoration, which is a bit more complex, but if you're still in the background, then you'll get a delegate callback. How are you testing this? What exactly do you see in your logs and how do you gather them? Why do you believe a connection has happened?

Comment: Correct I have the method but it did not get called. I will update question

Comment: I would first strongly suspect that your `alert()` method is the problem. After that, I would expect that you're not actually reconnecting. How are you demonstrating that this occurs? Simplify your app to the smallest program that will just scan and connect, and then reconnect on disconnect and log everything you can. Take out everything else in your program. If you build that, then you can share a simple reproducible case and explain, step by step, exactly what you're doing, what you think it should do, and precisely what it does.

Comment: To your underlying question: yes, iOS absolutely will reconnect in the background. You are either doing something wrong or you are misinterpreting what you're seeing. To figure out BLE issues, you need to be painfully precise and create a program that is as simple as you can possibly make it. Small test apps are the core of CoreBluetooth development.

Comment: 1) it is clearly reconnecting because as soon as you relaunch the app, it finds it right away 2) its already reproducible, the project has nothing except the code I've just posted you can run it yourself or I can upload it somewhere 3) alert cannot be the problem because I removed it and the same thing

Comment: I told you I already have a small test app that has nothing but 1 code file.